# pass field to distinct() in Django

Tags: django

I have a Django web app, using MYSQL.

model.py

```
class CourseInfo(TimeStampedModel):  
  code = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True)   
  title = models.CharField(max_length=190)       
  discipline_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  pattern = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PRESENTATION_PATTERN, blank=True, null=True,
                           help_text="Presentation Pattern")
```

I want to achieve this filter:

```
query_results_2 = courseInfo.objects.filter(discipline_id=id).values('discipline_code', 'code', 'title', 'pattern').distinct('discipline_code', 'code')
```

But seems like in mysql, distinct() could not have parameters.

How could I achieve this function？----  get 'discipline_code', 'code',
'title' and 'pattern' fields but only use 'discipline_code', 'code'  for distinct filter.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you know MySQL doesn't allow distinct based on multiple parameters, you can:

1. Make multiple query sets and chain them which even though is not recommended, but it does the job
2. Perform raw queries: [Raw querying Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Comment: how to do multiple querysets and chain them in my case？